# Modern List NewForm on Modern Site Page?

Tags: web-part, custom-list, custom-form, modern-experience

Any way to embed a Modern List New form into a modern site page? Dialog option does not seem to work and I see no web part option.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to get the URL for the form from the library and add it to the page as a link (or  using embed code) but may require maintenance. I imagine the feature will crop up in modern UI in due course.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using the embed webpart.

**Step 1 :** Copy the NewForm.aspx page url.

**Step 2 :** Add embed webpart on the page where you wish to show the form.

**Step 3 :** Open webpart property and add the embed code url.

```
<embed width="800" height="600" src="http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1" />
```

**Step 4 :** Save the page. It will start displaying the form on the page.

**Note:** IsDlg will remove all the header part from the page and will just show the form with ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Ankur's answer is incorrect. The modern page embed web-part does not support this. It only supports iFrame based embeds.

Using the iFrame alternative as below will work but it shows the form using the classic interface, including the toolbar.

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="http://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/lists/mylist/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the mordern expereince doesn't support webparts.
I had this expereince where I couldn't change to modern expereince because my classic expereince library had a Webpart.

You can have a look at this article where it also writes about why webparts arent allowed in the new expereince.
[Link to article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/What-is-Modern-SharePoint-and-Why-Should-I-care/ba-p/161941)